# How to get the number of entries or pages in Gitlab API paginated response (jobs/pipelines/etc)?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

When requesting a large number of entries in Gitlab API (for example, all jobs or pipelines), I used to get the total number of pages from the value of `x-total-pages` header in the response. With the introduction of the new pagination model in 15.9, though, this header is not available anymore (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/index.html#keyset-based-pagination). The new style of pagination provides the link to the next page only (`link` header). Therefore, one has to iterate over all pages to get the total number of entries (or pages).

Is there any way to estimate the number of pages or separate entries without retrieving them all one by one?

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/index.html#pagination-response-headers (same page, bit lower) says: *For performance reasons, if a query returns more than 10,000 records, GitLab doesn’t return the following headers: `x-total`, `x-total-pages`, `rel="last" link`.* That's not exactly the same what you write in the question.